# How to swap data in an array using splice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem. I am simply trying to swap the data in the array. I am using splice but its still keeping 1 element there at the end. How do I fully replace the data that is currently there without retaining the other?

```js
$("#test").click(function(){
fruits.splice(0, 1, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

});
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange"];

var col1 = ["Banana", "Orange","pies","pretzels"];
var col2 = ["Banana", "Orange"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to add and remove elements.</p>

<button id="test" onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Why 2 event listeners ...onclick and jQuery one?

Comment: Why you want to use `splice`? You can simply assign the new value to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [delete count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Parameters) as array length.

```
fruits.splice(0, fruits.length, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

Answer (score 1):

From MDN: [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> `array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])`

---

> #### start
>
> Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be
>   set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many
>   elements from the end.
>
> #### deleteCount
>
> An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should
>   specify at least one new element. If deleteCount is greater than the
>   number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of
>   the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.
>       If deleteCount is omitted, deleteCount will be equal to (arr.length - start).
>
> #### item1, item2, ...
>
> The elements to add to the array, beginning at the start index. If you don't specify any elements, splice() will only remove elements
>   from the array.

And your deleteCount is declared as 1, which is why it left out the other value, since you've 2.

```
fruits.splice(0, 1, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

Should be

```
fruits.splice(0, 2, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

Or better take @PranavCBalan approach to set the deleteCount as your variable length

```js
$("#test").click(function(){
fruits.splice(0, 2, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

});
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange"];

var col1 = ["Banana", "Orange","pies","pretzels"];
var col2 = ["Banana", "Orange"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to add and remove elements.</p>

<button id="test">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```